# Is there a better way to skip undefined variables in a loop?

Tags: javascript, logic

I'm writing a loop that runs a bunch of functions on some nodes in an object. If the objects are undefined, they should be ignored, unless a flag, m.testUndefined is true, then the opposite is true. My logic below works, but I wonder if there is a less wordy and more explcit way of achieving the same thing.

```
for (var i = tests.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var m = tests[i],
    subject = m.subject(raw),                       //get the right raw data
    isUndefined = typeof subject === 'undefined';

    if(m.testUndefined && !isUndefined){            //Flag for skipping defined subjects
        continue;
    }else if(!m.testUndefined && isUndefined){      //Skip all other undefined subjects.
        continue;
    }

    if( m.test(subject, m.params) ){
        m.tag(item.tags);                           //add tags if test success
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(m.testUndefined !== isUndefined) {continue;}` If the `m.testUndefined` always have value and only be either `true` or `false`.

Comment: it's usually true or undefined.

Comment: for such a small block that is skipped, isn't clearer to `if(!!m.testUndefined === isUndefined && m.test(subject, m.params)) { m.tag(item.tags); }`

Comment: force `m.testUndefined` to be boolean by `!!m.testUndefined` ...

Comment: @JaromandaX Agree, just forgot that we can use `!!value` to force a value to be `boolean`, and more importantly, do thing in `true` condition here should be clearer.

Comment: what is `m.testUndefined`? and what about `m.testUndefined || isUndefined` check?

Comment: @NinaScholz: is undefined is set right above it and testUndefined is a flag that is set if the test should be undefined.